# Create scrollable dropdown with max-height

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I'm trying to create a scrollable dropdown menu which doesn't extend past the current modal. I tried setting the max-height to 200 and overflow:scroll; but that didn't work. I added height:200px but that made a large gap between the current field and next fields (see picture). How can I make the dropdown only extend to about 200px without requiring to change the height?

css class:

```
.THIS .restrictDropdownHeight {
    z-index: 10 !important;
    max-height: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

html (within combo box):

```
<lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto"  size="12" largeDeviceSize="6" mediumDeviceSize="12" padding="horizontal-small">
                        <lightning:combobox aura:id="eSTypes" class="restrictDropdownHeight" label="Engagement Sub Types" variant="standard" options="{!v.engagementSubTypes}" disabled="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Engagement Sub Type is required"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
```

Pic:

[image]

Comment: please share your current approach, it will be easier to provide feedback (provide code please). Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
                                                        {'label': 'Label1', 'value': 'Label1'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label2', 'value': 'Label2'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label3', 'value': 'Label3'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label4', 'value': 'Label4'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label5', 'value': 'Label5'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label6', 'value': 'Label6'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label7', 'value': 'Label7'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label8', 'value': 'Label8'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label9', 'value': 'Label9'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label10', 'value': 'Label10'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label11', 'value': 'Label11'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label12', 'value': 'Label12'},
                                                        {'label': 'Label13', 'value': 'Label13'},
                                                        ]"/>

    <lightning:input name="someInput" value="This will, obviously, be not affected by combobox below."/>
    <lightning:combobox name="progress" label="Status" value="inProgress" placeholder="Select Progress" options="{! v.options }" onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>
    <lightning:input name="anyInput" value="Will this be pushed down?"/>

</aura:component>
```

**Style**

```
.THIS .slds-dropdown-trigger .slds-dropdown {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks @Kal for the feedback. that didn't work. The `height: 200px` causes a gap in between the elements, but I don't want a gap. I want the dropdown menu to be a max of 200px but show overtop of the other elements

Comment: Works for me, see screenshots in my answer above... could you be running into an interference from existing CSS? If so, please try creating a new component.